# Remotely access \\server\c$\users\user\My Documents

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remotely get the size of a users 'My Documents' folder using the C$ built in share.

I can browse the share, I can 'Set-Location' to the share but as soon as I try to 'Get-ChildItem' I get a permission denied.

I can't figure out if this is some built in limitation of Powershell?

Currently tried on PS2, PS3 same result.

(User has full access on both share and NTFS)

I've tried with providing the credentials using 'Get-Credentials' and I have also tried with 'New-PSDrive' mappings as well, same issue, the location is fine but as soon as I GCI it spits out 'PermissionDenied'.

```
$compList = [LIST OF COMPUTERS]
$exclude = [LIST OF EXCLUDED USERS]
$userSizes = @()

foreach ($computer in $compList){
gci ("\\$computer\c$\users\") | where {$exclude -notcontains $_.name}| foreach-object {
    $curUser = $_.name
    New-PSDrive -name "Map" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$computer\c$\users\$_\My Documents"
    $size = "{0:N2}" -f ((gci "Map:\" -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum /1MB)
    $properties = @{'Computer'=$computer;'User'=$curUser;'Size (MB)'=$size}
    $curObject = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties
    $userSizes += $curObject
    Remove-PSDrive -name "Map"
    }

}

$userSizes | Out-GridView
$usersizes = $null
```

Keep in mind that GCI in PS2 doesn't allow providing credentials and the 'FileSystem' provider doesn't either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uggh what a disgrace.

The reason was that the path is actually

```
\\[server]\c$\users\[user]\documents
```

For some unknown, god forsaken reason, Windows Explorer displays the path as 'My Documents' but the actual path is 'Documents'.

I have no idea why they would do this but there it is.  Working fine now, another few hours wasted...

Answer (score 1):

You might need credentials to use `Get-ChildItem` on a remote share, i've had it happen that i've had full access to my NAS but powershell gave me the same error "Permission Denied", it seems weird and i can't why it failed when i had full permissions but it worked when i gave powershell my credentials.

Try declaring credentials first:

`$creds = get-credential`

then using the credentials like so

`Get-ChildItem "\\server\c$\users\user\My Documents" -credentials $creds`

Comment: I should have put that in the question but I have tried with credentials also.

Comment: Are you able to post the code you are using so we can see if there is anything obvious and even try your code on our own machines?

Comment: Sure thing, added! I thought it might just be some limitation to do with PS versions or something someone might have had off the top of their head.

Comment: I don't think it would be a limitation, if it was you'd be getting a completely different error. Have you tried stepping through your code to see which part of your code causes the error, whenever i'm having trouble with a really command with multiple pipes i like to separate the pipes to make sure each individual part works.

If you run

    `foreach ($computer in $compList) {gci ("\\$computer\c$\users\")}`

by itself does it still give the same error? I'm actually quite new to powershell myself so my experience is only in PS3 so i'll have to leave this to the more powershell-inclined.

Comment: Even just running a simple - gci '\\server\c$\users\user\my documents'- from the PS command line fails with 'PermissionDenied' though I can browse to their no problems!

Comment: The only other thing i can think of that you could try is mapping the drive with `net use M: \\server\c$\users\user\My Documents` and then try a `gci M:` to see what happens.

I'm sorry, short of a few google searches i'm not really helping you get closer to the answer, hopefully someone can provide another answer so we can both learn more about this mysterious beast we call powershell.